# Sent message event jabber.net in c#

Tags: c#, xmpp

I'm developing a .net project usign jabber.net library. I need to be able to intercept the SENT messages by the user I'm connectd to. For instance, I connect my app using jabber to the user "a@b" . Everytime the user "a@b" SENDS a message using gtalk, I would like to receive a notification.
Actually the OnMessage event is called only when a message is RECEIVED, and the OnWriteText event is called only if I send a message from my app but not if the user uses gtalk...

How can I achieve al this? thanks.

Comment: Clarification question: are you saying that OnWriteText fires when talking to a server other than gtalk, but not on gtalk?

Comment: No, I was just asking how to understand of a message has been sent or delivered. After a long search, xmpp protocol Does not offer this service.